# Bring existing AWS secrets into Cloud Formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-parameter-store

Initially I created secrets outside of Cloud Formation using Custom Resource. Now I want to migrate those existing secrets to existing Cloud Formation Stack without creating a new one. Is there a way to incorporate those existing secrets using CLI(preferably) or any other way to achieve this?
I'm aware of drift detection operation but doesn't seem like it allows an entire secret to migrate. I referred this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret` is [not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html). This means that you have to create new secrets from scratch in CloudFormation and delete the old ones. Otherwise, you have to keep them fully separate as you have now.